# Make droplets stand out on this photo

Tags: gimp, images, effects, photomontage

I'm trying to modify this image (with Gimp) to make the droplets on the surface where H905 is written stand out as much as possible, and everything else to stand out as little as possible.

Would anyone have any tips?

[image: faint droplets on surface where H905 is written]

At the moment, I have this: the operations I have performed are:
Colours, Colour Balance:
        -> Midtones, Cyan 100
        -> Highlights, Magenta 100
Hue-Saturation:
        -> Hue, -20
ColoriseL
        -> Hue, 0
        -> Saturation, 0
Brightness-Contrast:
        -> Contrast, 10

[image: droplets more visible]

Comment: it going to be tough to make things stand out of a photo that are not really there in the original - not enough tonal contrast to make anything out of without getting really manual.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to make the droplets to stand out is to add new ones to your picture and exaggerate that effect.

You can find a droplet or condensation image online, ideally grayscale, and apply it to your yellow tank using some [layer mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html) ([Gimp Layer mask](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Layer_Masks/)) and blending modes. You can also colorize the droplets any way you want.

**Example in Photoshop (Should be similar in Gimp):**

[image: image to combine to create droplets]

Will give this, using the droplets at 35% transparency on a layer, and the luminosity blend effect (apparently "value" mode is a close one in Gimp). These were not even colorized but could be for even better result:

[image: example drops of water and condensation amplified in Photoshop]

If it's too much, simply keep parts of the droplets and erase some using the mask and a soft brush and play with the transparency of your layers.

This took me a big 2-3  minutes and it's way faster than trying to adjust the levels and the colours, or to try to isolate the droplets!